# 2 Menu javascripts conflicting with echother

Tags: javascript, menu

I have 2 javascript menus that are conflicting with eachother. They are opening eachother up, as in, if I click the menu button for 1 menu, it will open up the other menu. Here is the javascripts for both menus, so the question is, how can I get them to not mess with each other?

This is the new javascript here, and when I added this javascript, it started interferring with the existing javascript menu.

here is the menu for the first javascript

```
<div class="topnavmem" id="myTopnavmem">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">link1</a>
  <a href="#">link2</a>
  <a href="#">link3</a> 
  <a href="#">link4</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="iconmem" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnavmem");
  if (x.className === "topnavmem") {
    x.className += " responsivemem";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnavmem";
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the existing javascript menu, it is the old menu, then I added the new javascript menu above
it started to interfer with this script, so how can I make each javascript different, I think the issue is the myfunction?

here is the menu for the second javascript

```
<div class="topnav">
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#" style="background: #243144;padding: 6px 16px;">Link</a>
     <div id="topnav-subnav">       
      <a href="#">Link</a> 
      </div>
    <a href="#" style="background: #243144;padding: 6px 16px;">Link</a>
         <div id="topnav-subnav">       
      <a href="#">Link</a>   
      </div>
    <a href="#about" style="background: #243144;padding: 6px 16px;">Link</a>
         <div id="topnav-subnav">       
     <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>
    <a href="# style="background: #243144;padding: 6px 16px;">Link</a>
         <div id="topnav-subnav">       
        <a href="#">Link</a>     
      </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="topnavicon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you calling the functions?

Comment: Hey buddy I fixed the question, and added the function, maybe you can look now?

Comment: You can't have two different functions with the same name. Give them different names.

Comment: Hey thanks, the issue is, how do you give them 2 different names, when I tried, I broke the script. Show me once and I will learn for life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same name for both functions. You need to give them different names, which ideally should be more descriptive than just `myFunction`.

So you can change the second code to

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="topnavicon" onclick="topNavFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function topNavFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```